# How to obtain validator expression used when creating a MongoDB collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, database-schema, jsonschema

I have a collection in MongoDB created with a [validator expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). Is there a way, ideally with the Java driver, to obtain the schema after the collection was created? I have checked the [javadoc of MongoCollection](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html) but found nothing that would do the trick. Did I miss anything?

Comment: The database command is [`listCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections). The linked question/answer shows accessing the structure for obtaining the validation expression.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @NeilLunn !